# Java : How to access UNC location

Tags: java, unc

same as title;
how to access to UNC location in ShareFolder?

```
URL uri = new URL("file:\\\\x.x.1.10\\myUNC");
File file = new File(uri);
```

or

```
URL uri = new URL("file://x.x.1.10/myUNC");
File file = new File(uri);
```

also doesn't works.

Comment: Does the same path work in Windows explorer?

Comment: yes, the same path, i think it's cannot be loaded well

Answer (score 7):

Just:

```
File f = new File("\\\\x.x.1.10\\myUNC");
```

Comment: Thx for your Answer, and i have one more Ask.

Comment: i want to save marshalled XML files to UNC address but can't UnMarshaller with Error "xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file://x.x.1.10/UN ....." but another location can load well

Answer (score 1):

Using **forward slashes** (`/`) instead of backslashes with the `file` protocol *will* work to access a UNC location:

```
URI uri = URI.create("file:////SERVER/some/path");
```

Be sure, however, not to call `URI.normalize()` or `URI.resolve()` or it will break the UNC URI by removing too many slashes. The official bug: [URI.normalize() ruins URI built from UNC File](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4723726)

[More on UNC paths in java](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/UNC_Paths#Programming_with_UNC_paths)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows2012 R2 this worked for me

```
java.nio.file.Files.copy(
    Paths.get("\\\\xxxx/CRR/S20-1141_2020-03-16_ADDN1.txt"), destination, standardoptions);
```

The file share server is \\ (with \ escaped) but rest all /

using Java 8 240 build

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your answer - for starters, if you want a line break in the post editor to be in the post (look at the preview), append two spaces to the end of the line. What is that `new`, are the parentheses really unbalanced, and how did `copy()` enter the scene?