# Is JENKINS Extensible Choice Parameter compatible with linux?

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a simple freestyle job in Jenkins locally on a windows box. I have created a single parameter for the job using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin

However, Once I create this same job in another instance of jenkins running on  linux CloudBees Jenkins instance, the pluggin no longer provides files in the configuration or dropdown when I run with parameters.

Notice the linux on left and windows on right. Is this really releated to linux or perhaps another issue?

[image]

Does this require significant work to get the job that is running on Linux Jenkins instance being able to reference  UNC path that we use when we run Job on windows instance? Not as up to speed as others with Linux so I need help on this one

Linux able to access windows fire share?
Where is the gap in my understanding of how file shares work in this way?

I would imagine that if a plugin exists for Jenkins, unless otherwise stated in documentation, the plugin should work on whatever is running jenkins

Perhaps linux has an etirely different way of working with files/shares path(s)?

Comment: can you give an exact example of the base directory path?

Comment: \\vgbuild01\D$\BuildArtifacts\DummyService

Comment: you wrote it is cloudbees instance. is vgbuild01 resolvable DNS name for cloudbees? Is vgbuild01's CIFS accessible  from outside network?

Comment: Yes, the DNS should be resolvable. I dont know about CIFS. It sounds to me like the way linux treats file shares vs. how windows treats them. Is CIFS related here still?

Comment: linux is not related here at all. Jenkins is written in Java and you should be able to access your UNC path as well. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926148/java-how-to-access-unc-location for example. It sounds me like network issues

Comment: Well, the job can have a windows powershell configured to execute ( on windows label) and that build agent can access that same share path, so that makes me wonder why the build agent is able to access but job cannot. Doesn't that rule out network issues?

Comment: where is windows slave is located? is it cloudbees instance too?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: Im considering trying to use $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job>/builds/<build>/archive as base directory